# restrict external access to a swf file using cq5 dispatcher

Tags: aem

I have an html page into which an swf is embedded, and this swf has some information which should not be disclosed, however on security scan GET request to this swf is exposing that information. I thought of using the filter rule in dispatcher as below

```
     /0048 { /type "deny" /glob "* *sample.flash.swf *"   }  #
```

After that the page itself is not able to access the swf, so I think the above method of restriction is wrong.
May I know how we can make this swf accessible only to the page where this swf is embedded and else where this needs to be restricted from getting accessed.

Comment: In Apache, you could rewrite requests for the file that don't also contain a [HTTP Referer header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). Though because of the way the web works, this is really just security theatre: there's nothing to stop users including this themselves via curl, etc.

Comment: @anotherdave so you say this can be achieved using our webserver,if so can you please add more details

Comment: It's the same instructions the docs list here for [preventing image hotlinking](https://hkg3vl3269.p2g.netd2.hk.hsbc:5433/libs/granite/core/content/login.html?resource=%2Fsystem%2Fconsole&$$login$$=%24%24login%24%24&j_reason=unknown&j_reason_code=unknown), though just to reiterate that this won't stop any but the most basic attempts to grab the SWF.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure its not possible to handle this at dispatcher.

Ideally you should not put any sensitive information in the swf file in the first place.

If you must, consider rendering the content through a servlet that will require a token which is available only on the page. Also see [CSRF Protection Framework](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/security/csrf-protection.html)

Comment: +1 for the information, "rendering the content" in the sense you mean to say "rendering the swf", if that is the case I can render that swf only through actionscript only :(

Comment: not sure about the actionscript part but yes I meant the swf file.